# Hugo post directory appearing on homepage, but not posts

Tags: hugo, blogdown

For my blogdown-created website (using the [Xmin](https://themes.gohugo.io/hugo-xmin/) theme), the posts directory - from which I can view individual posts - appears on the homepage, instead of individual posts.

https://joshuamrosenberg.com/

[image]

This seemed to happen after updating to the lastest version of Hugo. The source for my website is [here](https://github.com/jrosen48/utk-homepage). I'm a bit puzzled about what to do: do you have any advice?

Comment: Is your XMin theme up-to-date? I fixed this issue last year https://github.com/yihui/hugo-xmin/commit/6123be24bf4a7517ae9cbf05882b62f52684d16d. I'm not sure if your version includes this fix.

Comment: ah hah, that was it! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is due to a breaking change in Hugo 0.57.0, and [I have fixed the issue](https://github.com/yihui/hugo-xmin/commit/6123be24bf4a7517ae9cbf05882b62f52684d16d) in the latest version of the XMin theme. Basically you need to replace

```
{{ range (where .Data.Pages "Section" "!=" "") }}
```

with

```
{{ $pages := .Pages }}
{{ if .IsHome }}{{ $pages = .Site.RegularPages }}{{ end }}
{{ range (where $pages "Section" "!=" "") }}
```

in the template file `layouts/_default/list.html`.