# Hugo displaying post directory rather than most recent posts

Tags: hugo

I found a similar problem but the solution posted doesn't work for me:

[Hugo post directory appearing on homepage, but not posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59919045/hugo-post-directory-appearing-on-homepage-but-not-posts)

Perhaps as it's because I'm using a different Hugo theme?

https://github.com/invinciblycool/lekh

In the [demo](https://agitated-yonath-d9c445.netlify.app/) posts appear on the homepage, but using the latest version of Hugo, only my post directory appears on the homepage.

This is the list HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
{{ partial "head.html" . }}

<body>
  {{ partial "page_header.html" . }}

  <h3>Posts</h3>

  <div>

    <!-- orders content according to the "publishdate" field in front matter -->
    {{ range .Pages.ByPublishDate }}
    <div>
      <a href="{{ .Permalink }}">{{ .Title }}</a><br />
      <time>{{ .Date.Format "January 2, 2006" }}</time>
    </div>
    <br />
    {{ end }}
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What happens if you use `.Site.RegularPages.ByPublishDate` instead of `.Pages.ByPublishDate`?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've tried that code and the issue persists